# Newer Samsung devices can't display webpages in their built-in SMS app

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, samsung-galaxy

When I open an URL (say https://www.google.com) in a SMS in Samsung's built-in Messages app, it's opened in the in-app browser, where a blank page is immediately displayed, and stays blank instead of displaying the website.

1. Is this a known Samsung/Android bug?
2. Is there a known workaround?

**To reproduce:**

1. Receive (or send) an URL in a SMS **in Samsung's built-in Messages app**.
2. Tap on the URL in the SMS:

   1. The app opens the webpage in its in-app browser instead of opening it in Chrome.
   2. Observe a blank page is immediately displayed, and stays blank.

**To work around:**

1. Rotate the device orientation (e.g. *portrait -> landscape*).
2. Observe the page finally appear in front of your puzzled eyes!

**What kind of page works?**

None. Even this one fails to be shown:

```
<html>
  <body>How I wish you'd show me immediately!</body>
</html>
```

A few more surprises:

- `alert('ah, ha!')` works immediately!
- The CSS style `background-color` works immediately!
  That is, the blank page uses the color defined in this rule.
- `document.body.innerHtml('Show this, at least!')` doesn't help.

**Known affected devices**

- Samsung Galaxy S6
- Samsung Galaxy S7
- Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge

Looks like you shouldn't buy Samsung's newer devices!?

*Messages in-app browser version: 51*

Comment: If I send myself a SMS on a S7 with the following URL, the issue you raised is also reproduced: https://www.google.com ...!!!

Comment: Maybe there is an overlay showing up. Maybe get a way to refresh the page on after load once if some div is not immediately visible using jquery? We have the same issue. iOS, LG, BlackBerry, SGS4Active works fine.

Comment: I think this question is ontopic, it just has to be refactored and part of it extracted into an answer. The question is "How to display a webpage in built in sms app?". The answer are your provided workarounds.