# Android link in sms opens blank website

Tags: javascript, android, browser, sms

We send an SMS to a user using a Marshmallow Android device.
User clicks on the link and opens up in a what seems like a browser within the SMS app.

It looks like this in-SMS browser app does not support JavaScript and thus the website overlay loader does not disappear.

(We have the same issue with the UAM browser which opens up when Wi-Fi hotspot auto popup in the notifications.)

Is there something one can do to let the website open with the normal browser like chrome instead of this in SMS app browser by adding something to the url or do something else?

Examples of websites doing this:

- https://www.supersport.com
- https://www.alwayson.co.za
- https://www.cellc.co.za
- try other random websites as well and see.

Workaround: Click "MORE" on the top right corner and select "Open in Browser" but it is not ideal.

Comment: You can also copy the link and paste it in the browser, but i don't think that you can change the browser with something in the URL.

Comment: Is it Marshmallow in general, or is it specific to Samsungs? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39110293/newer-samsung-devices-cant-display-webpages-in-their-built-in-sms-app

Comment: Thank you for the post. Looks like samsung devices